# Multiple date picker in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to modify the following code to show multiple calendars on click of a textbox. The first textbox works with the calendar, the second one doesnt show anything.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="///code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );
  </script>

 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 fsdfsdfsd
 
 sdf
 sdf
 sdf
 
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
  fsdfsdfsd
 
 sdf
 sdf
 sdf
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: don't use multiple inputs with same ID... id's are supposed to be unique per page

Comment: you can use $("input#datepicker") to select your datepicker inputs with their ids . But I would recommend to use $("input.datepicker") with inputs class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` must be unique. You can use `class` as the selector

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="///code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".myDatepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );
  </script>

 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="myDatepicker"></p>
 fsdfsdfsd
 
 sdf
 sdf
 sdf
 
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="myDatepicker"></p>
 
  fsdfsdfsd
 
 sdf
 sdf
 sdf
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker3" class="myDatepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you select your datepicker id element with an ID, so only the first ID will be selected (IDs have to be unique ! )
change it for a class and it should work